# How do I get the standard file extension given a MIME type in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, mime-types, file-extension, delphi-xe7

Is there a built-in way to get the standard extension of a given MIME type in Delphi (XE7)?

I'm looking for the easiest and most general way to implement a function that would be called like this:

```
fileExt := GetExtension('text/xml');
```

Comment: not that I know of, but a quick google finds this: https://www.thoughtco.com/file-extensions-and-mime-types-3469109

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I hoped for a system function, as the set of MIME types changes over time. For example, in the table you linked, there's no entry for docx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\text/html, value Extension.

Comment: Surely there's an API or some standard  way of encapsulating this. Without documentation saying this is stable it looks like fragile registry hacking.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indy uses this registry key too so we can think this is "official" way.

Comment: There is no Win32 API to query Window's MIME database, but its Registry key is documented in multiple places in MSDN, so its location is known to be valid and unlikely to change between Windows versions.  Besides, Indy doesn't rely solely on the Registry anyway. It has a long list of defaults, and then uses the Registry to override/fill-in any missing gaps.

Answer (score 5):

It seems Indy has a built in function for that, on **TIdThreadSafeMimeTable**:

```
Uses
  IdCustomHTTPServer;


function GetMIMETypeDefaultExtension(const aMIMEType: String): String;
var
  mimetable: TIdThreadSafeMimeTable;
Begin
  if not(aMIMEType.Trim.IsEmpty) then
  Begin
    mimetable := TIdThreadSafeMimeTable.Create(true);
    try
      result := mimetable.GetDefaultFileExt(aMIMEType);
    finally
      mimetable.Free;
    end
  End
  else
      result := '';
End;
```

**Edit:** function fixed to use TIdThreadSafeMimeTable directly without custom http server.

Comment: You may also use *TIdThreadSafeMimeTable* in the same unit directly (no need to create a server)

Comment: changed the anser to use that class instead, as you suggested.

Comment: `TIdThreadSafeMimeTable` is intended for use with `TIdHTTPServer`, since it is a multi-threaded server whose worker threads frequently require access to cached MIME info. There is a non-threadsafe `TIdMimeTable` in the `IdGlobalProtocols` unit, which also has standalone `GetMIMETypeFromFile()` and `GetMIMEDefaultFileExt()` functions (which use `TIdMimeTable` internally). In the example above, since it is creating and destroying the table every time it is called, using `TIdThreadSafeMimeTable` is overkill, just use `TIdMimeTable` or even `GetMIMEDefaultFileExt()` instead.

Comment: true, but in the function above you'd have to create and destroy the instance anyway, calling buildcache anyway(directly or indirectly), so, you wouldn't gain anything by using the non-threadsafe version. and when thats the case, I'd much rather have a general purpose function that I wont have to worry about if its thread-safe or not.

Answer (score 5):

Indy's `IndyProtocols` package has a `TIdMimeTable` class and standalone `GetMIMETypeFromFile()` and `GetMIMEDefaultFileExt()` wrapper functions in the `IdGlobalProtocols` unit, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobalProtocols;

function GetExtension(const AMIMEType: string);
begin
  Result := GetMIMEDefaultFileExt(AMIMEType);
end
```

Just know that internally, `GetMIMEDefaultFileExt()` creates and destroys a `TIdMimeTable` object, and that object re-builds its list of known extensions and MIME types every time it is created.  If you are going to be querying MIME extensions frequently, it would be worth creating your own `TIdMimeTable` object (or `TIdThreadSafeMimeTable` if you need to share the table across multiple threads) and reuse it each time:

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobalProtocols;

var
  MimeTable: TIdMimeTable = nil;

function GetExtension(const AMIMEType: string);
begin
  if MimeTable = nil then
    MimeTable := TIdMimeTable.Create;
  Result := MimeTable.GetDefaultFileExt(AMIMEType);
end;

initialization
finalization
  MimeTable.Free;
```

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobalProtocols, IdCustomHTTPServer;

var
  MimeTable: TIdThreadSafeMimeTable = nil;

function GetExtension(const AMIMEType: string);
begin
  if MimeTable = nil then
    MimeTable := TIdThreadSafeMimeTable.Create;
  Result := MimeTable.GetDefaultFileExt(AMIMEType);
end;

initialization
finalization
  MimeTable.Free;
```

Answer (score 1):

For more current versions of Delphi, you can use the `TMimeTypes` class in the unit `System.Net.Mime`

There are two methods which you can use to seed the internal dictionary to perform the lookup.  The first `AddDefTypes` will add the standard types, and the method `AddOSTypes` will add any defined by the host OS (for windows, it does a registry crawl). If you call `TMimeTypes.GetDefault` it will construct a TMimeTypes instance using both methods the first time it is called (singleton).

Comment: This was added in Delphi 10.2.3 
https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2018-march-rtl-10-2-3.html